# Optimizing basic method memoization with early return

Tags: ruby, memoization

When implementing basic memoization in Ruby, is there a pattern or simple way to return the memoized instance var if the value predicates on a more complex evaluation before hand?

Say the assignment of `something` requires an intense calculation, is Ruby smart enough to return the instance variable if it's present, or will `something` always be assigned within the scope of that method before setting `@some_value`?

```
  def some_value
    @some_value if @some_value.present? # possible?
    something = something_else.try(:method_name) || another_something.method_name # prevent this from evaluating after execution
    @some_value ||= MyClass.new(property: something.property)
  end
```

What would a better memoization pattern be to implement what I have?

Comment: The first line of your method returns `@some_value` or `nil`, but as that value is not captured by a variable, the line serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how your code is currently written, the "intense calculation" will always occur. Ruby uses implicit return unless you explicitly use the keyword `return`, so, even if `@some_value` is present, the code will still execute to the last line.

```
def some_value
  return @some_value if @some_value.present? # possible?
  something = something_else.try(:method_name) || another_something.method_name # prevent this from evaluating after execution
  @some_value ||= MyClass.new(property: something.property)
end
```

So, if you want to return `@some_value` if it is present, and not run any code afterwards, you will want to use explicit return. See above.

Now, Ruby will check if `@some_value` is present, and if that is `true`, the value is returned, otherwise, it will continue with the calculation.

Comment: Doh! Thank you for elaborating on that :)